# Distinguish between instances of user controls with mvvm-light

Tags: user-controls, mvvm-light

I have two instances of a File Browser user control, the control is just a button and a text box, but I need two instances, think a diff utility.  Once the user has selected a file for each control I want to enable a button which will perform an action on both of the files.

The problem I am having is how to distinguish between the instances of the controls in order to determine that both files have been selected.  I think I would like for my DoSumthinViewModel to only have string properties which the FileChooserViewModel fulfills.

At first I had a single ViewModelLocator with a property which returned a new instance of a the FileChooserVM when accessed, but this just didn't seem right and I could not distinguish between the instances.  I then went down the path of a separate Locator for the FileChooser but realized that each control would be talking to the same locator instance and thus the same FileChooserViewModel again.

So, what would be a good technique for working with individual instances of the same ViewModel?

Thanks,

Shane Holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DoSomethingViewModel could have two properties of type FileChooserViewModel that your controls are bound to, then check their string properties for a value.

A simplified version of your FileChooserViewModel could be...

```
public class FileChooserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public const string FilePathPropertyName = "FilePath";
    private string _filePath;
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return _filePath; }
        set
        {
            if (_filePath == value) return;
            _filePath = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(FilePathPropertyName);
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("FilePath Updated"));
        }
    }
}
```

And your DoSomethingViewModel might look like this...

```
public class DoSomethingViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DoSomethingViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }

    public const string FileChooser1PropertyName = "FileChooser1";
    private FileChooserViewModel _fileChooser1 = new FileChooserViewModel();
    public FileChooserViewModel FileChooser1
    {
        get { return _fileChooser1; }
        set
        {
            if (_fileChooser1 == value) return;
            _fileChooser1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(FileChooser1PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string FileChooser2PropertyName = "FileChooser2";
    private FileChooserViewModel _fileChooser2 = new FileChooserViewModel();
    public FileChooserViewModel FileChooser2
    {
        get { return _fileChooser2; }
        set
        {
            if (_fileChooser2 == value) return;
            _fileChooser2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(FileChooser2PropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string BothFilesChosenPropertyName = "BothFilesChosen";
    public bool BothFilesChosen
    {
        get
        {
            var result = false;
            if (FileChooser1 != null && FileChooser2 != null)
                result = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileChooser1.FilePath)
                      && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileChooser2.FilePath);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg.Sender is FileChooserViewModel)
            RaisePropertyChanged(BothFilesChosenPropertyName);
    }
}
```

The NotificationMessageReceived method is called with a NotificationMessage is sent from FileChooserViewModel's FilePath property setter, and it in turn raises the property changed event on the BothFilesChosen property.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DoSomethingProject.Views.DoSomethingView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DoSomethingProject.Views"
             DataContext="{Binding DoSomethingViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <views:FileChooser DataContext="{Binding Path=FileChooser1}" />
        <views:FileChooser DataContext="{Binding Path=FileChooser2}" />
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BothFilesChosen}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Another way to do this would be to handle the PropertyChanged event on each FileChooserViewModel property, but I prefer using messaging because event handling means you need to make sure you un-handle the events, and this can get messy leading to memory issues when events are missed.

Comment: That's close to where I am now, however I believe that the FileChooser[1,2] properties change events won't get fired, because they would never get set correct? The problem I am having is still distinguishing between notifications of FileChooserViewModel.FilePath.

Comment: You're totally right. My example didn't properly update the BothFilesChosen property. I changed my examples to use messaging.

Comment: That got it, I did not realize that the property notification had a sender on it, so I was able to use that to distinguish between chooser1 and chooser2.  I had taken to putting a Token object on the FileChooser and using that to send a specific message, it seemed to make my FileChooserViewModel smelly but would that be better than receiving every string changed notification?

Comment: You could also create your own message class inheriting from MessageBase. In fact, that's what I do in practice. That way you can register with something like Messenger.Default.Register<MyCustomMessage>(this, MyCustomMessageReceived).

Comment: If you add your own message, do you put both the Send<> and the RaisePropertyChanged in the set for the property?

Comment: Are you talking about the FilePath property? If so, then yes. You'll still want the FileChooserViewModel to raise the PropertyChanged event when the FilePath value changes.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was talking about. Thanks for your help.